# Concatenate several CSV files in a single dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have currently 600 CSV files (and this number will grow) of 50K lines each i would like to put in one single dataframe.
I did this, it works well and it takes 3 minutes :

```
colNames = ['COLUMN_A', 'COLUMN_B',...,'COLUMN_Z']
folder = 'PATH_TO_FOLDER'

# Dictionnary of type for each column of the csv which is not string    
dictTypes = {'COLUMN_B' : bool,'COLUMN_D' :int, ... ,'COLUMN_Y':float}

try:
   # Get all the column names, if it's not in the dict of type, it's a string and we add it to the dict
   dictTypes.update({col: str for col in colNames if col not in dictTypes})  
except:
    print('Problem with the column names.')
    
# Function allowing to parse the dates from string to date, we put in the read_csv method
cache = {}
def cached_date_parser(s):
    if s in cache:
        return cache[s]
    dt = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors="coerce")
    cache[s] = dt
    return dt

# Concatenate each df in finalData
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.csv")) 
finalData = pd.DataFrame()
finalData = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, dtype=dictTypes, parse_dates=[6,14],
                    date_parser=cached_date_parser) for file in allFiles ], ignore_index=True)
```

It takes one minute less without the parsing date thing. So i was wondering if i could improve the speed or it was a standard amount of time regarding the number of files. Thanks !

Comment: I don't expect much of a speed boost from this comment, but it's useful to understand nonetheless. Like any reasonable function of this kind, the `pd.concat()` function will take not only sequences (eg, `list` or `tuple`) but any iterable, so you don't need to create a never-used list. Instead, just give `pd.concat()` a generator expression -- a lightweight piece of code that `pd.concat()` will execute on your behalf to populate the data frame. Like this: `pd.concat((pd.read_csv(...) for file in allFiles), ...)`

Comment: It's a little bit slower with this but at least i've learned something !

Comment: Where do you get `colNames` and `folder` from?

Comment: Sorry forgot those, one is a list of names, the other one is the path of the folder in a string

Comment: Did you try it without the cached date parser? Does it actually make it faster (because you have a lot of duplicates)?

Comment: Yes as i said at the end of my question, it takes approximately one minute less without the cached date parser

Comment: @FMc Generator expressions do not always lead to a speedup. In cases where the function needs to read all input data before creating the output, constructing a list first would not be slower. Sometimes it could even be slightly faster (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results/11964478#11964478)) because list comprehensions avoid the function call overhead in `list(<gen_exp>)`.

Comment: Have u tried replacing `date_parser=cached_date_parser` with `infer_datetime_format=True` in the `read_csv` call? The API document says reading could be faster if the format is correctly inferred.

Comment: @GZ0 True enough, but as noted in the first sentence, my comment was aimed less at speed than general understanding. If memory is the primary constraint, for example, a generator expression can help.

Comment: @FMc In this case, which is probably the same as what I mentioned in my earlier comment, the function needs to consume all the inputs (and create a list) from the generator expression first before generating the output (because the size of the output dataframe needs to be known before memory allocation). Therefore I do not expect memory usage to be lower with generator expressions either.

Comment: @GZ0 Good shot, it reduces by 30 seconds, thanks !

Comment: How often do you do this? 
Are all csv-files changed or are there new files that should be aggregated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my untested feedback on your code. Some remarks:

- Encapsulate the functionality as a named function. I assumed `folder_path` as the main "variant" your calling code might want to vary, but your use case might "call" for a different first argument.
- Use PEP8 recommendations for variable names.
- Comb/separate the different concerns within the function:

  1. gather input files
  2. handle column types
  3. read CSVs and parse dates
- Depending on how much each of those concerns grows in size over time, multiple separate functions could organically grow out of these separate paragraphs, ultimately leading to a whole utility package or class (depending on how much "instance" configuration you would need to preserve, moving the `column_names` and `dtypes` parameters to object attributes of a `class XyzCsvReader`'s `__init__` method.)
- Concerning the date parsing: probably the bottleneck is not caused by caching or not, but how often you invoke the heavy machinery behind `pd.to_datetime`. My guess is that only calling it once in the end, but with `infer_datetime_format` enabled will be much faster than calling it once per row (even with your manual cache).

```py
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

def read_xyz_csv_folder(
        folder_path,
        column_names=None,
        dtypes=None):
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, "*.csv"))

    if column_names is None:
        column_names = [
            'COLUMN_A',
            'COLUMN_B',  # ...
            'COLUMN_Z']
    if dtypes is None:
        dtypes = {
            'COLUMN_B': bool,
            'COLUMN_D': int,
            'COLUMN_Y': float}
    dtypes.update({col: str for col in column_names 
                   if col not in dtypes})

    result =  pd.concat((
            pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, dtype=dtypes)
            for file in all_files),
        ignore_index=True)
    
    # untested pseudo-code, but idea: call to_datetime only once
    result['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
        result[[6, 14]],
        infer_datetime_format=True,
        errors='coerce')
    
    return result
        
# use as
read_xyz_csv_folder('PATH_TO_FOLDER')
```

*Edit: as suggested by user FMc in their comment, switch from a list comprehension to a generator expression within `pd.concat` to not create an unneeded list.*

Comment: thanks, same idea than GZ0 in the comment with the  `infer_datetime_format=True` but it's better by a few seconds with your untested idea

Answer (score 1):

How often do you do this?

Are all csv-files changed or are there new files that should be aggregated?

- Perhaps you could reuse the dataframe and just add the new files.
- Otherwise you could create a dictionary, and store it as a json. Then you would not have to read all files, and when reading the json to a `dict() d`, you could just use `d.update(new_dict)`.